# Powerset and ensembles in Coq

Tags: coq

I have the following definition for a monoid

```
Class Monoid
  (K : Type)
  (op : K -> K -> K)
  (unit : K) := {
    (* few properties here *)
  }.
```

that I can easily instanciate, for exemple, for the monoid `(N, +, 0)` :

```
Instance Monoid_Instance_1 : Monoid nat plus O.
```

It works fine.

My problem is that I want to instanciate monoids such as `(P(P(G)), Union, Empty_set)`, where `P(P(G))` is the powerset of the powerset of a set G. Ideally, I would want to do something like :

```
Parameter G : Set.
Instance Monoid_Instance_2 : Monoid (Power_set (Power_set G)) Union Empty_set.
```

It doesn't work because of the `Ensemble (Ensemble G)` type returned by `Power_set` (and of course the double Power_set above is fiction)

Do you know how I could do that ? Do I need to change my definition of `Monoid` ?

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Power_set` is an operation on `Ensemble`s, not on `Set`s.

```
Require Import Coq.Sets.Powerset.

Parameter S : Set.
Parameter E : Ensemble S.

Check Power_set _ (Power_set _ E).
```

`Ensemble S` already is the powerset monoid. Every `E : Ensemble S` is a subset of `S` and vice versa (read `x : X` as `x ∈ X`). `Ensemble`s are predicates: `Ensemble X = (X -> Prop) = (X -> 2) = P X`.

```
Conjecture C1 : forall x y z, Union _ (Union _ x y) z = Union _ x (Union _ y z).
Conjecture C2 : forall x, Union _ Empty_set x = x.
```

Actually, these conjectures assume predicate extensionality, which is not constructive, but can be safely added.

You might be able to prove something like

```
Power e1 : Ensemble (Ensemble t1)

In Empty (Power e1)

In e1 (Power e3) -> In e2 (Power e3) -> In (Union e1 e2) (Power e3)
```

, but you won't be able to prove

```
Power e1 : Type

Empty : Power e1

Union : Power e1 -> Power e1 -> Power e1
```

. `Power e1` is not a `Prop`, `Set`, or `Type`, it's a predicate.